# ArgumentNullException in ValidationContext.set_DisplayName when binding an action parameter model

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

When POSTing a form to a .net core MVC action, I get an ArgumentNullException with the following callstack:

```
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext.set_DisplayName(string value)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations.Internal.DataAnnotationsModelValidator.Validate(ModelValidationContext validationContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.ValidateNode()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.Visit(ModelMetadata metadata, string key, object model)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.VisitChildren(IValidationStrategy strategy)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.VisitComplexType(IValidationStrategy defaultStrategy)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.Visit(ModelMetadata metadata, string key, object model)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ObjectModelValidator.Validate(ActionContext actionContext, ValidationStateDictionary validationState, string prefix, object model)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that one of the model properties had a `[Display(Name = "")]` attribute. The empty string causes this exception in the binder code. Replacing by `[Display(Name = " ")]` (with a space instead of an empty string) worked around the issue.

Comment: Never imagined that I will come back to ASP.NET again. You saved me from hours of madness. In my case, it was `[DisplayName("")]`